# Why properties applying only on first element rather than its respective elements

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on any checkbox of added to-dos css property applies only on the first element.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const container = document.querySelector(".to_dos_container");
input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    add = `<div class="task_container">
    <input type="checkbox" class='done'>
    <p class='task'>${input.value}</p>
  </div>`;
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", add);
    input.value = "";
    lineThrough()
  }
});

function lineThrough() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll(".done");
  checked.forEach((c) => {
    c.addEventListener("click", (p) => {
      var task = document.querySelector(".task");
      if (c.checked) {
        task.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        task.style.color = "gray";
      } else {
        task.style.textDecoration = "unset";
        task.style.color = "unset";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="text_area">
  <input type="checkbox" class="disabled" disabled>
  <input id="input" placeholder="Create a new todo..." type="text">
</div>
<div class="to_dos_container">
</div>
```

I want when I click on checkbox of added to-dos css property should apply on its respective to to-do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".task")` selects the first element with the class `.task`. You need to use `nextElementSibling` to select the element that follows the element with class `.task`, since there is only two sibling elements inside the div it will select the corresponding checkbox.

Change this

```
var task = document.querySelector(".task");
```

To this

```
var task = c.nextElementSibling;
```